# In Java, can a variable or parameter set the parent of a subclass?

Tags: java, swing, oop, polymorphism, relationship

### Context

I'm creating an RPG character-generator program using Swing with JPanels and the like, along with other JComponents, with these components returning their data in a certain order based on the Dependencies list (see below). I'd like the components to contain some extra data and functions so I'd likely want to extend, like

NewField extends JTextField

NewButton extends JButton

NewLabel extends JLabel and so on and so on.

### Problem

I can manually type these out, sure! But they're all gonna have common variables like "Dependency List" or "InitialOrder" and so on. **I'm looking for a relationship that provides that template data, both functions AND local variables**. I've tried...

1. Interfaces, but those don't create non-static variables
2. A SuperClass extending JComponents, but that doesn't include the specifics of the JTextField and JButton methods. I'd have to redeclare EVERYTHING in that new class, and I'd rather avoid that.
3. A Generic class that create a JComponent object and returns that whenever required, but that's a PURELY JTextField component. "getDependencies" wouldn't work for it, I'd still need a whole list. Even with the whole  situation, setting limits didn't help.

Note: The dependencies are just a list of fields that have to be read first as the user can define conditions in a text file to change some things. For example, if the user wanted a number of houses to be between 50 and 100, and about 3 to 5 people per house, the NUMBEROFHOUSES field would have to generate a value BEFORE the NUMBEROFRESIDENTS field generated its value, as it has to do so for a number of times equal to the NUMBEROFHOUSES generated value. The Dependency list for NUMBEROFRESIDENCES would contain NUMBEROFHOUSES, meaning when the list of all the fields is read as listed, the "GENERATE NUMBEROFHOUSES" string would come before the "GENERATE NUMBEROFRESIDENCES" string.
Dependencies is just a "make sure these fields are read first" list

### Question

Like generics that create a generic object, ***can I define a class whose extension is based on another variable or parameter?***

E.g.: Class NewComp extends T

Class NewButton extends NewComp

### Example

---

### Current method

```
class NewButton extends JButton{
    private ArrayList<String> dependencies;
    NewButton(){super();}
    public ArrayList<String> getDependencies{return dependencies;}
    public void setDependencies(ArrayList<String> newDeps){dependencies = newDeps;}
}

class NewTextField extends JTextField{
    private ArrayList<String> dependencies;
    NewTextField (){super();}
    public ArrayList<String> getDependencies{return dependencies;}
    public void setDependencies(ArrayList<String> newDeps){dependencies = newDeps;}
    public void aSpecificNewTextFieldMethod(){...}
}

class NewLabel extends JLabel{
    private ArrayList<String> dependencies;
    NewLabel (){super();}
    public ArrayList<String> getDependencies{return dependencies;}
    public void setDependencies(ArrayList<String> newDeps){dependencies = newDeps;}
    public void firstNewLabelMethod(){...}
    public void secondNewLabelMethod(){...}
}

class CompManager{
    private JPanel p;
    CompManager(JPanel p){
    this.p = p;

    p.add(new NewButton(), new NewTextField().setText("Fake"), new NewLabel());

    Component[] c = p.getComponents();

    for(Component comp: c){

        if(comp.getClass().equals(NewField)) {//do something}

    }
}
```

### Method in question

```
class NewComp extends <T>{
    private ArrayList<String> dependencies;
    NewComp(){Super();}
    public ArrayList<String> getDependencies{return dependencies;}
    public void setDependencies(ArrayList<String> newDeps){dependencies = newDeps;}
}

class NewButton extends NewComp<JButton>{
    NewButton(){super();}
}

class NewTextField extends NewComp<JTextField>{
    NewTextField (){super();}
    public void aSpecificNewTextFieldMethod(){...}
}

class NewLabel extends NewComp<JLabel>{
    NewLabel (){super();}
    public void firstNewLabelMethod(){...}
    public void secondNewLabelMethod(){...}
}

class CompManager{
    private JPanel p;
    CompManager(JPanel p){
    this.p = p;

    p.add(new NewButton(), new NewTextField().setText("Fake"), new NewLabel());

    Component[] c = p.getComponents();

    for(Component comp: c){

        if(comp.getClass().equals(NewField)) {//do something}

    }
}
```

Even if the answer's no, I'd love to hear some alternative solutions!
If I haven't made the problem clear enough, please say so!

Comment: You are over-thinking your problem and most importantly over-using inheritance and I think are heading towards a coding nightmare if you continue on this path. Focus more on the use of composition, on simplicity, and on limiting complexity (cyclomatic complexity)

Comment: For example with regards to components that I use and create (and I've used many), I inherit GUI components about 5% of the time (mostly a JPanel that needs its paintComponent overridden to do drawing) and the other 95% of the time, use straight GUI components that have properties set as needed, but that are not inherited. If many are needed with similar properties, I'll do this via a factory method.

Comment: Suggestion also, get rid of the needless chattiness of your question and instead focus on making your question understandable. A small compilable runnable code example would go a long way towards this goal. Do go through the [help] links, the [mre] link and the [ask] link to see how to improve this and your future questions.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! While I think the setup and context can explain my thought process, clarity couldn't hurt! Basically I want to rewrite the JComponent class to add a few more methods/variables. I'll look up the Factory Method, I've seen that pop up once before... Thanks again, stay safe!

Comment: Please [edit] and improve your question, adding any new key information to the question itself. And again, please read the links that I've given since your question, as written, is in danger of being closed if not improved to meet site standards.

Comment: Also,  look up the M-V-C design pattern (which stands for model-view-controller), and then study it. You may then want to focus more on the model than on the view (which you appear to be currently doing)

Comment: Alright, I've done some editing. I think I've kept the key information in. If it needs any more changes, please let me know

Comment: Can you tell us more about what *exactly* these dependencies are. What specific information do they hold and how is this information used? (again, as an [edit] to the question)

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: Note that your dependencies information belong in the model and not in the view at all.

Answer (score 2):

> can I define a class whose extension is based on another variable or parameter?

Yes, on further thought, as a matter of fact, you can. Something like this is known as the [Abstract Factory Design Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/abstract-factory) (please check out the link for a decent tutorial on this). This allows you to create objects of classes with specific characteristics that can be *determined at run-time*, which is what I *think* it is you are trying to do. Because the Factory is "abstract" (usually starting with an interface), you have the flexibility of creating multiple concrete versions of it as the need arises and as your program evolves, and each concrete factory created can then be used to create multiple different components (or logical entities). It is very powerful and very flexible.

Having said this, I still stand by most of the comments that I've made to your original post, including:

- You may be over-using inheritance rather than focusing on the easier to use of extension by composition
- Perhaps need to focus more on the *model* of your program, the *non-GUI* logical underpinning that is separate from the concrete GUI components that make up the other main part of the program, the *view*
- As for Swing, I still would recommend avoiding inherting most of the Swing components that you create and use and instead using components "out of the box", but setting properties a needed, using a factory method if you need to create multiple similar components, and only using inheritance when you need to override a concrete components *behavior*, such as doing drawing in a JPanel.
- Look up the M-V-C design pattern, which stands for model-view-controller, and then focus first on the model part of your code, since much of the things that you describe belong there and not in the GUI components proper (again, the view).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, definitely a good read! I'll edit my question to give a specific scenario; I think the Abstract Factory Design Pattern is TOO flexible as I'm only looking to add about 3 methods and variables for each. Also, the order they're read isn't really set by the user, or at least isn't required: There's a template file that can be changed if so needed, but most users would just use it as is. Though I don't think I've made myself clear enough so that's my bad. I'll try to be more clear!